# I am trying to create a container within azure using the python sdk getting error

Tags: python, sdk, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to create a container within azure using the python sdk
when doing a test from the command interpreter, I ran the commands below and getting the following error:

```
>>> from azure.storage import BlobService

>>> blob_service = BlobService(account_name='kevtest', account_key='HFohNOxxxxxxxxxJzXao3NeSPOvozRvNFIQSVqO5yOT5+Aastl3sdcJKg+pKBk+oewM7Y6OuLDPbj7qq+7OQ==')

>>> blob_service.create_container('images')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/storage/blobservice.py", line 190, in create_container
    _dont_fail_on_exist(ex)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/__init__.py", line 818, in _dont_fail_on_exist
    raise error
azure.WindowsAzureError
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's likely an issue with your account name/key, but without the error message, I can't say for sure.  You've censored your account key for this post, and so of course I can reproduce an authentication error.

Unfortunately the console can't display the full error message, but if you run it in an IDE or console that can display unicode strings without converting to ascii, you should be able to see the error message and confirm whether or not it's a problem with your account name/key.